# An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org

Tags: php, wordpress

I was not able to install plugins in my WordPress site.

I am getting the following error when i try to install a new plugin.But its allowing me to upload a plugin and then to install it.

"An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org  or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please  try the support forums."

Comment: So you are allowed to upload an install plugins but you get errors ??  Have you considered the possibility that something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server configuration ? Have you tried the support forums?

Comment: s i tried but i couldn't resolve it.

Comment: wordpress support forums for resolution..

Comment: Well, I assume you went through a discussion with them? What were the problem solving steps? What was the conclusion?  Did they not reply? If so, how long did you wait?

Comment: I was given with the below solution,                                                        /** EXAMPLE - proxy settings */
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', 'proxy.url.com');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '1234');
define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', '');
define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', '');
define('WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS', 'localhost');                                       But it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

After spending more time is this I have resolved this by looking at

```
wp-config.php
```

Make sure this flag is false, if it's true update couldn't be happen

```
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', false);
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on fedora but after searching for a while it seems that SELinux denied permission to make outgoing network connections.
You can find evidence of this in /var/log/audit/audit.log. For example:
type=AVC msg=audit(1531585576.912:201): avc: denied { name_connect } for pid=802 comm="php-fpm" dest=443 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:http_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0

To resolve the problem:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Now SELinux will permit WordPress to make outgoing network connections to check for updates.

Comment: Imo this is the best option, it allows you to keep selinux in enforce mode while also allowing the apache server to host the WP site.

Answer (score 3):

To debug this set WP_DEBUG to true in wp-config.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

In my case this shows a curl error attempting to reach host: api.wordpress.org when loading the add new plugins page.

On my server curl was already installed correctly. You can run this command to install it on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

The solution in my case was to restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After this the plugin page resolved normally.

Set Debug back to false when you confirm everything is working:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution ：wp-config.php in add code

```
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', false);
```

Also appeared ：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z1fU.png)

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. |Try Again|

Is there a better solution, looking forward to sharing

Comment: Can't load add theme in the past。
After use, the theme can be loaded, but the prompt still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn SELinux to permissive to see if it was causing the problem.

And to do that open this file:

```
nano /etc/selinux/config
```

Then change the line `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=permissive`

Then reboot:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: this may cause some serious rebooting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Steps I would use:

1. Validate that the filesystem allows WordPress to write to the WordPress directories.
2. Validate that you have allowed outgoing traffic in your web server, firewall and internal network.

When I have run to that error it has usually been some misconfiguration in my machine, either denying write access or outgoing network access from the web server processes.

What do your PHP and web server logs have? Is the site on localhost or on a production server?

Comment: its on production server.

Comment: Hopefully the server provider is not blocking ports or certain domains from connecting to external networks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps that you can look for:

1. make sure you have sufficient space on your domain
2. try uninstalling all the available plugins one by one and check (eg : plugin like WP Video Lightbox causes issue like this sometimes
3. Disable all plugins and then reactivating them
4. if you are running wordpress on your virtual machine, try ping test on your server side.
5. if nothing works try installing new version of wp

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. In my case (on windows server), I just activated the php curl extension in my php.ini and it worked.

So make sure that the curl extension is activated on your php.ini

Answer (score -1):

add `ob_start()` at top of `wp-config.php` that work for me

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.